# Set P3P code in HTML

Tags: html, internet-explorer, p3p

I've researched this subject alot. But one thing I don't get if it is possible to set a P3P tag in plain HTML? Just before the first -tag.

Im trying to get an iFrame-login solution to work in IE.

I have just found code example in PHP, ASP.NET and so on but not in plain HTLM, if that is even possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [P3P and PHP session problem with iframes in Internet Explorer 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283720/p3p-and-php-session-problem-with-iframes-in-internet-explorer-9)

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue recently trying to serve static HTML from AWS S3.

Unfortunately, it is **not possible** to set Compact Policies without sending server-side response headers.

This means that you cannot set a Compact Policy on staticly-served HTML content.

[Section 2.4.2 of the P3P deployment document](http://www.w3.org/TR/p3pdeployment#Compact_Policies_Bad) explicitly mentions this (emphasis mine):

> 1. There is only one mechanism for sites to serve compact policies; they are sent as HTTP response headers. Thus, **if a site is unable or unwilling to add HTTP response headers, compact policies cannot be used.**
> 2. The HTML element META with the http-equiv attribute is sometimes used to simulate the effect of adding HTTP headers to HTML content. ... the http-equiv mechanism should not be used to send a P3P compact policy header, as this information may not be available to a client until after it has processed the cookies in the response.

The `<meta http-equiv='p3p' content='CP="..."'/>` and `<link rel="P3Pv1" href="...">` elements cannot set the Compact Policy either - it must be a response header.

The bottom line is this:

Are you able to send the `p3p` response header?

- Yes: Add the header with the appropriate policy and you are done.
- No: You are out of luck and are unable to set a Compact Policy.

#### For Amazon S3:

The `p3p` header is considered a user-defined key so it can only be added as `x-amz-meta-p3p`.

Since `x-amz-meta-p3p` != `p3p` the browser will not accept it as the correct header.

**Therefore you cannot set a Compact Policy on AWS S3 content.**